# PHP Version 5.3 vs Version 5.6 and above

Tags: php, arrays, versions, square-bracket

to my understanding, PHP version 5.6 and above supports the use of [] (square brackets) for array. I have a functioning code:

```
$sortedMainCatArray[$letter][] = $eachMainCategory;
```

that is working well on PHP version 5.6. What this code essentially does it that it pushes array values into $sortedMainCatArray with a preset key. (eg a/b/c) The outcome looks something like this when using print_r.

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
              (
                [mainCatID] => 33
                [mainCatDesc] => Alternative Medicine
                [mainCatAddedDate] => 2017-12-18 10:35:31
                [mainCatStatus] => active
              )

          [1] => Array
              (
                [mainCatID] => 32
                [mainCatDesc] => Anesthesiology
                [mainCatAddedDate] => 2017-12-18 10:29:48
                [mainCatStatus] => active
              )
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
              (
                [mainCatID] => 1
                [mainCatDesc] => Blood & Infection
                [mainCatAddedDate] => 2017-12-18 10:29:28
                [mainCatStatus] => active
              )
        )
)
```

However, since PHP version 5.3 do not support the use of [] (square brackets), I have to modify my code. What I have was:

```
$sortedMainCatArray[$letter] = array($eachMainCategory);
```

However, this only resulted in each alphabetical array to only have one value. An example can be seen below, where under the "A" category, there is only one value (Anesthesiology) instead of two (Alternative Medicine & Anesthesiology).

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
              (
                [mainCatID] => 32
                [mainCatDesc] => Anesthesiology
                [mainCatAddedDate] => 2017-12-18 10:29:48
                [mainCatStatus] => active
              )
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
              (
                [mainCatID] => 1
                [mainCatDesc] => Blood & Infection
                [mainCatAddedDate] => 2017-12-18 10:29:28
                [mainCatStatus] => active
              )
        )
)
```

How else can I go about to modify my code to work on PHP version 5.3 like it has worked on version 5.6 without the use of [] brackets? Appreciate all the help given! Thank you!

Comment: PHP 5.3 also supports `$sortedMainCatArray[$letter][] = $eachMainCategory;`. It doesn't support `$var = [];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short array syntax was [introduced](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0) in 5.4. But you misunderstood. This supports `[]` instead of `array()` syntax for *literal* declarations.

However, the syntax

```
$array[$index][] = $someVar;
```

has nothing to do with short array syntax. It's been valid since the beginning of PHP. You can use this syntax in older version, too.

When the code is changed to

```
$sortedMainCatArray[$letter] = array($eachMainCategory);
```

it basically says that do not create a sub-array at $letter index of the main array (multiple calls to this line results in multiple elements in the subarray) but assign `array($eachMainCategory)` to that index (multiple calls to this line assign the same array to that index multiple times). To sum up, leaving

```
$sortedMainCatArray[$letter][] = $eachMainCategory;
```

for both PHP versions is OK.

**UPDATE**

Accessing an array element at a specific index when that array is returned by a function is called `array dereferencing support` and was also added in 5.4, so the one liner allowed by it `functionThatReturnsArray()[$index]` can only be done in two expressions (lines) in PHP prior to 5.4 as shown in the [PHP manual examples](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-62) section:

```
// on PHP 5.4 
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously  
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your explanation which helped to clear my misunderstanding about the whole [] brackets issue. However, at time when I would like to access a specific associate array value via its key, for example, returnResults($recordSet)[0], the system will give me a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['" error. 

How else can I solve this issue if the square brackets are "not allowed"?

Comment: @GadmanTang, see updated answer. `functionThatReturnsArray()[$index]` can only be done in two expressions (lines) in PHP prior to 5.4.

Comment: @marekful Hey man, it works! Thank you so much for trying to help me to understand better about the difference in support from each php versions! Have a good day mate!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
array_push($sortedMainCatArray[$letter], $eachMainCategory);
```